# getting # after extracting href from <a> tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/marseille-13/jardinier , I have a problem with pagination.
The link of next page is stored in  tag. i get # after a['href'] not the link

```
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
Footer = soup.find(class_='result-footer')
divpagination= Footer.find(class_='pagination')
atag=divpagination.find("a", {"id": "pagination-next"})
print(atag.get('href'))
Output : #
```

Note: I Make the request without the Accept-Encoding header, that way the server doesn't compress the message to be sent

html  tag : 
            Suivant

tag with beautifulsoup:

Suivant

Comment: Please edit your question to add the printed value of `atag['href']` so we can see _exactly_ what you get.

Comment: I see no next page

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you inspect the page's source code in your browser (or just print it), this link uses js for navigation.

There are additional (non standard) properties to the tag so you can eventually try to reverse engineering the whole thing (check the tag attributes values, click the link in your browser and compare with the new page's effective url).

If it doesn't work then you'll need a headless browser and code to drive it (selenium being the canonical python solution).

Comment: If I use a headless browser all the content of the page will be encrypted

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's (eventually) compressed (gzip'd) - and hopefully the browser knows how to decompress it else it couldn't do anything with it xD.